# How to use rulesets with ValidateAsync in FluentValidation's world?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'd like to use [ruleSets](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#rulesets) with my FluentValidation classes when I call `validateAsync`, but I haven't found anything about it in the documentation, which provides examples for `validate` only, nor in issues of the [project github repo](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).

With rulesets I can keep my validation rules in the same class, without rulesets I need to create validation classes for every case where I need validation for the same class.

What is the solution for this? If there is no ruleSet parameter for ValidateAsync what is the reason?

Answer (score 3):

**ValidateAsync** does have a *ruleSet* parameter. For it to be available you need to add the *FluentValidation* namespace:

```
using FluentValidation;
```

Usage is like the regular (synchronous) **Validate**:

```
var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(account, ruleSet: "nameOfRuleSet");
```

Answer (score 0):

In library Fluent validation 10 onwards.

```
using FluentValidation;
var validationResult = await 
validator.ValidateAsync(account,options=>options("nameOfRuleSet"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In 10 versions and above

```
await validator.ValidateAsync(account, options => options.IncludeRuleSets("default","update"),cancellationToken);
```

Without a cancellation token

```
await validator.ValidateAsync(account, options => options.IncludeRuleSets("default","update"));
```

Where an update is a new ruleSet in a validator

```
 RuleSet("update",
    () => {
     ...
     ...
  });
```